# Trigger submit button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried that code that I posted on fiddle.

I want to `trigger` that save button when enter key is pressed, the save button submits the form using ajax. It should trigger the save button when `text > 0` in the **span**.

```js
$(document).on('focusin', '#commentDescription', function(e) {
  $('.comment-submit').slideDown(500);
  $(this).css({
    'border-bottom-left-radius': '0',
    'border-bottom-right-radius': '0'
  });
});

$(document).on('focusout', '#commentDescription', function(e) {
  if ($('#commentDescription').text().length === 0) {
    $('.comment-submit').slideUp(500);
    $(this).css({
      'border-bottom-left-radius': '5px',
      'border-bottom-right-radius': '5px'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: #d0d2ff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  resize: none;
}

.textarea[contenteditable]:empty::before {
  content: "Write a comment...";
  color: gray;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #f4f5f7;
}

.textarea:focus {
  outline-color: rgb(223 223 223 / 0%);
  outline: 0;
}

.comment-submit {
  width: 99%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px 10px 8px 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.btn-comment-submit {
  padding: 0.215rem 0.800rem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-container">


  <form id="commentSubmitForm">
    <span class="textarea" role="textbox" name="description" id="commentDescription" contenteditable></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" id="commentTaskId" value='1'>
    <div class="comment-submit" style="display: none;">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-comment-submit" id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/shami003/2g9n7cq0/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the keycode for the enter button.

[**Keycode**](https://keycode.info/) for ***Enter Key*** is `13`

When the user presses the ***Enter Key*** then you can use

```
 event.keyCode === 13
```

to find if the user has pressed the ***Enter Key*** or not.

Now to prevent the `new line` when ***Enter Key***  is pressed, we can do this with CSS also.

```
.textarea br {
  display: none
}
```

Code:

```js
$(document).on('focusin', '#commentDescription', function(e) {
  $('.comment-submit').slideDown(500);
  $(this).css({
    'border-bottom-left-radius': '0',
    'border-bottom-right-radius': '0'
  });
});

$(document).on('focusout', '#commentDescription', function(e) {
  if ($('#commentDescription').text().length === 0) {
    $('.comment-submit').slideUp(500);
    $(this).css({
      'border-bottom-left-radius': '5px',
      'border-bottom-right-radius': '5px'
    });
  }
});

$("#commentDescription").keyup(function(event) {
   
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
       var spanContent = $('#commentDescription').text();
       
       if(spanContent.length > 0){
          //$("#submit").click();
          console.log("Form Submitted")
       }
       else{
         console.log("Please write some comment.")
       }
   }                                                                        
 });
```

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: #d0d2ff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  resize: none;
}

.textarea[contenteditable]:empty::before {
  content: "Write a comment...";
  color: gray;
}
.textarea br {
   display: none
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #f4f5f7;
}

.textarea:focus {
  outline-color: rgb(223 223 223 / 0%);
  outline: 0;
}

.comment-submit {
  width: 99%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px 10px 8px 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.btn-comment-submit {
  padding: 0.215rem 0.800rem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-container">
  <form id="commentSubmitForm">
    <span class="textarea" role="textbox" name="description" id="commentDescription" contenteditable></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" id="commentTaskId" value='1'>
    <div class="comment-submit" style="display: none;">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-comment-submit" id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it always showing 'Please write some comment' in console and go to next line

Comment: This is working fine now but how to prevent new line, look at updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shami003/2g9n7cq0/21/

Comment: @IhtishamKhan I have updated by code, please look, and it it helps you then accept this as answer

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding event on that (Edited)

```
$(document).on('focusin', '#commentDescription', function(e) {
    $('.comment-submit').slideDown(500);
    $(this).css({
        'border-bottom-left-radius': '0',
        'border-bottom-right-radius': '0'
    });

    if($('#commentDescription').val()) {
        $("#commentDescription").keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                $("#submit").click();
            }                                                                        
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I wanted that submit only when the #commentDescription is 'focused and there is some input text'

Comment: It won't work that way, I tested it. on('focusin') is triggered when only you focus textarea, after that event code there won't work

Answer (score 1):

Now it's fired if the text of the textarea is > 0

```js
$(document).on('focusin', '#commentDescription', function(e) {
  $('.comment-submit').slideDown(500);
  $(this).css({
    'border-bottom-left-radius': '0',
    'border-bottom-right-radius': '0'
  });
  $('#commentDescription').bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode == 13) && (event.target.textContent != '')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#submit").click();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your solution is somehow working. I have added "e.preventDefault();" to prevent adding new line. Now this is working in fiddle but not in my view cause this form is appended using jquery and I have used  '$(document).on('focusin','#commentDescription' ,function(e){
    $('.comment-submit').slideDown(500);
    $(this).css({
                'border-bottom-left-radius': '0',
                'border-bottom-right-radius': '0'
              });
  });

Comment: Instead of '$(#commentDescription).on('focusin', function(e){
    $('.comment-submit').slideDown(500);
    $(this).css({
                'border-bottom-left-radius': '0',
                'border-bottom-right-radius': '0'
              });
  }); somewhere else

Comment: So how can I use this logic using this bind